# Factorization Question

Tags: prime-factorization, unique-factorization-domains

I need help factoring this problem: anything is appreciated. I have attempted this problem but I haven't been able to solve it so...here it is:

$$\frac{a^2 - ab + ab^2}{a^2 - b^2 + ab^2 +b^3}$$

Thanks

Comment: [If only the result matters](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(a%5E2-ab%2Bab%5E2)%2F(a%5E2-b%5E2%2Bab%5E2%2Bb%5E3)&t=crmtb01). Otherwise, what do you want -- is it homework, where does that arise from?

Comment: Do you mean $$\dfrac{a^2-ab+ab^2}{a^2-b^2+ab^2+b^3}$$?

Comment: yes thanks mario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the denominator is given by $$a(a-b+b^2)$$ and the denominator $$a^2-b^2+b^2(a+b)=(a-b)(a+b)+b^2(a+b)$$
does this help you?
and the fraction is given by $$\frac{a(a-b+b^2)}{(a+b)(a-b+b^2)}$$

Comment: it does help but it needs to be simplified further.

Comment: the end answer should be : a/ a+b

Comment: i want to know how to get to that answer